# Where is iText source code?

Tags: itext

The iText download page (at http://itextpdf.com/download.php) lists http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/ for downloading the source.  This URL returns a response indicating that the content has been permanently moved:

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

The location is nonsense, as you can see, so TortoiseSVN, which I was using, gave me an error message. Does anyone know how to get the source?

Comment: Are you checking out from the URL in the address bar or `svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk`?

Comment: The iText source code is currently on GitHub: https://github.com/itext

Answer (score 9):

What you say is incorrect. See screen-shot. The code can be browsed at http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/

[image]

Also in the screenshot, you see buttons **RO** / **HTTP**.
Next to **RO**, it says:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk itext-code
```

If you click **HTTP**, it says:

```
svn checkout http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk itext-code
```

Those are the two command lines you can use if you have an SVN client.

Furthermore, you can download the source code in a ZIP from the files entry on SourceForge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/iText5.4.2/

If this answers your question, please update your question and remove all references to "nonsense".

Comment: Huh, why did somebody spend a reputation point on downvoting this answer? The allegation of the OP is proven false; just try the links in my answer to make sure. The screen shot also proves that the link is correct.